# Does Handsontable support server side pagination like jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, handsontable

Does Handsontable support server side pagination like jqgrid? [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/)

Comment: May be this will help. I am not familiar with jqgrid. [pagination with handsontable](https://forum.handsontable.com/t/handsontable-pro-any-plugin-for-pagination-like-client-side/1966/6)

Comment: ok, seems it doesn't support server side pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, found it doesn't support server side pagination.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a pagination where you define some methods in the table definition and that magically handles the pagination I think the answer is NO, HT focus more on the presentation of the data to be more like Excel sheets leaving the pagination to each implementation. At the beginning I was not very happy about that, but you can handle the pagination by yourself using any strategy you decide and later updating the content of your table using "[loadData](https://handsontable.com/docs/6.2.2/Core.html#loadData)".

Now, if you are looking for a scroll pagination approach, that is something I have not explored enough, HT has a very smart scroll strategy where only creates the elements that needs making the render very fast when working with large sets of data, so, I am not sure that type of scroll you are expecting it is possible as HT needs to know the total data size to correctly draw the vertical scrolls, maybe if you create empty rows for all data your expecting giving a static height each and later when you detect new data is needed while scrolling you fetch from the server side the missing data you can achieve the same result, here seems that feature was discussed [Infinite scroll](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/607)